# Vue app with Netlify form throws error binding to events

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, netlify

I am trying to hide/show a div if a form-input has a value. This works just fine with a regular form but if I implement it with [netlify-forms](https://www.netlify.com/docs/form-handling/) I get the following error:

`Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: "setting getter-only property "message""`

```
<form name="newsletter" method="POST" data-netlify="true">
  <input @input="email = $event.target.value" type="email" name="email">
  <div :class="{'hidden': email === ''}">
     <div data-netlify-recaptcha="true" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I also tried `@focus` and `@blur` instead of `@input` but the error is always the same.

Without the `data-netlify="true"` it works as expected so I suspect it to have something to do with Netlify injecting something into the form.

Comment: As I read netlify will parse html.and modify it, that will surely lead to dom mismatch errors and it won't work with vue

Answer (score 1):

In Netlify's [guide](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2018/09/07/how-to-integrate-netlify-forms-in-a-vue-app/) on Netlify Forms + Vue, they say that the way SPAs are rendered can prevent Netlify's bots from HTML-editing the form to link it with their services.

> By default Vue renders client side but the Netlify post processing bots expect HTML on site deploy. Any netlify form attribute tags included in a Vue app would only be inserted into the DOM client-side, rather than in the HTML and thereby runs the risk of being totally overlooked by the build bots.

> To handle this, you have two options. You can either pre-render your application or add the netlify form to your static HTML file in your public folder.

So either pre-render your HTML (which gives an added speed and SEO bonus), or give netlify a static form to attach itself to, which you can then hide and replace with your nice Vue form on the client.